# Relational Algebra, when to use projection and selection in these queries?

Tags: sql, relation, relational-algebra

I'm trying to understand when to use the selection and projection operators.  My current understanding is that selection returns tuples that fit a specified criteria, and projection creates a new relation from the relation it acts upon, but only with the attributes specified.  For example:

```
σ(attribute="criteria"^(relation))
```

returns all tuples with the specified attribute value, from relation "relation".

```
Π name (relation)
```

would find the list of names from the relation "relation", disregarding the any other attributes.

From this sample database, with asterisk-marked primary keys:

```
employee(*personName*, street, city)
works(*personName*, companyName, salary)
company(*companyName*, city)
manages(*personName*, managerName)
```

I have to:

A) Find the names of all employees who work for M&T Bank.

```
Π personName(σcompanyName = “M&T Bank” ^(works))
```

B) Find the names of all companies which might be recorded in the database.

```
Π companyName (company)
```

C) Find the names of all employees who are not managers.

```
Π personName (works) - ΠpersonName(manages)
```

Basically, are the above query attempts right? And is my understanding of these operators correct and complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer A) is correct (also I do not know what is the meaning of `^` in your notation, so I've just ignored it).

For B you should keep in mind that the companies might be recorded not only in the *company* table but also in the *works* table. Hence, your answer should be `Π companyName (company) U Π companyName (works)`.

For C you should also be a bit more careful with identifying the employees. One could argue that former employees still listed in *employee* but not in *works* should also be considered. Depending on your (or your teacher's) point of view you might need to use `Π personName (works) U Π personName (employee)` instead of `Π personName (works)`.

A more serious issue in C is the identification of managers. `ΠpersonName(manages)` are individuals being managed, not managers. Managers are `Π managerName(manages)`.

Hence, for C you might prefer `(Π personName (works) U Π personName (employee)) - Π managerName(manages)`.

In general, your understanding of projection and selection is correct, but you need to be slightly more careful when formulating the answers.

Comment: The carat was supposed to mark a superscript; sorry if that was unclear.  This all makes sense, though; thank you so much for your helpful reply.